# In a .js file can I update a variable after ajax responsetext is processed?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

So I have a .js file that I need to retreive a variable from a PHP file. No, I can't make the server treat .js as a .php though.

So anyway, I have this script

```
function getPHPVariable(){
var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!

try{
    // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
    ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
} catch (e){
    // Internet Explorer Browsers
    try{
        ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (e) {
        try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e){
            // Something went wrong
            alert("Your browser broke!");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
// Create a function that will receive data sent from the server
ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
         variableIWant = ajaxRequest.responseText;
    }
}
ajaxRequest.open("GET", "phpfile.php", true);
ajaxRequest.send(null); 

}
```

Now the variableIWant is what I need to be used in another string later on, but everytime I call it it is shown as undefined. I do know that the variable is being sent properly though because by simply adding alert(variableIWant); underneath the responseText line, it properly alerts me of the variable.

So for simplicity, is it possible to get the variableIWant and use it in another string, or am I SOL because it has to wait for the readystate?

Comment: "I can't make the server treat .js as a .php though" — So what? Use a `.php` file. Browsers care about content-type, not file extension. There are no file extensions in URIs.

Comment: Sorry, I have to have a .js file. It's something being called by a script tag on dozens of other sites.

Comment: I appreciate the help, but it needs to be this file and a .js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where do you define `variableIWant`?

If you just assign it inside the `onreadystatechange` function it's just available within the scope of that function.

So you have to either declare it outside all of the functions or write

```
window.variableIWant = ajaxRequest.responseText;
```

**UPDATE:** just as [Quentin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8878129/45948) points out, just put the code inside the `onreadystatechange` function...

either:

```
ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (ajaxRequest.readyState == 4) {
        variableIWant = ajaxRequest.responseText;
        longString = "The variable I retrieved is: "+variableIWant+". Isn't this nice?";
        document.getElementById('theDivPart').innerHTML = longString;
    }
}
```

or:

```
ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (ajaxRequest.readyState == 4) {
        update(ajaxRequest.responseText);
    }
}

function update(value) {
    longString = "The variable I retrieved is: " + value + ". Isn't this nice?";
    document.getElementById('theDivPart').innerHTML = longString;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/roberkules/JgZ2B/

by the way, is there a reason why you don't use a javascript framework? e.g. like jquery that takes care of all the ajax hassle? your code in jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.get('http://sumary.org/phpfile.php').done(function(data){
    $(function() {
       $('#theDivPart').html('The variable I retrieved is: ' + data + '. Isn\'t this nice?');
    }); 
});
</script>

<body>
<div id="theDivPart"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: I have `variableIWant` defined outside of all functions.  Even with `window.variableIWant = ajaxRequest.responseText;` I still am only getting undefined as the variable when used in a string. Is it possible to show it as the undefined but when it is updated, it changes it later on?

Comment: i think it would be the best if you would supply more of your code... (maybe on jsfiddle) to fully understand what's going on.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/BqDST/

This example will have the alert show the correct value (which is "correct"), while the string that is being placed in the div tag on the page shows undefined as the value

Answer (score 0):

> So for simplicity, is it possible to get the variableIWant and use it in another string, or am I out of luck because it has to wait for the readystate?

It has to wait for the readystate function to be called, and that won't happen until the HTTP response returns.

Put your logic in the function you assign to readystate, that is what readystate is for.